# How to display number of posts in wordpress category including subcategories?

Tags: php, wordpress

While listing category, I want to show how many posts are there including subcategories. I tried this:

```
$cat_parent_ID = isset( $cat_id->category_parent ) ? $cat_id->category_parent : '';

            if ($cat_parent_ID == 0) {

                $tag = $cat_id;

            } else {

                $tag = $cat_parent_ID;

            }
$q = new WP_Query( array(
                    'nopaging' => true,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $tag,
                            'include_children' => true,
                        ),
                    ),
                    'fields' => 'ids',
                ) );
                $allPosts = $q->post_count;

                echo $allPosts;
            ?>

            <?php _e( 'posts found', 'agrg' ); ?>
```

The above works fine if category has no childs. But if I click on category which has subcategories, I see `0 posts found` even if there are posts, but all of them are in subcategory (so 0 posts in parent category but some posts in subcategory)

Where did I go wrong and what should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this function:

```
function wp_get_cat_postcount($id) {
    $cat = get_category($id);
    $count = (int) $cat->count;
    $taxonomy = 'category';
    $args = array(
        'child_of' => $id,
    );
    $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$args);
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        $count +=$tax_term->count;
    }

    return $count;
}
```

this function will return total post counts from the specified category and its child categories (if any), just by passing the category id. *i hope it works for you, thanks..*

Comment: If a post is assigned to multiple subcategories, it is counted more than once, so you get wrong result with this function

Comment: Wrong result if a post is in multiple category or it's have parent and child both selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
function wt_get_category_count($input = '') {
global $wpdb;
if($input == '')
{
    $category = get_the_category();
    return $category[0]->category_count;
}
elseif(is_numeric($input))
{
    $SQL = "SELECT $wpdb->term_taxonomy.count FROM $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE $wpdb->terms.term_id=$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id=$input";
    return $wpdb->get_var($SQL);
}
else
{
    $SQL = "SELECT $wpdb->term_taxonomy.count FROM $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE $wpdb->terms.term_id=$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id AND $wpdb->terms.slug='$input'";
    return $wpdb->get_var($SQL);
}
}
```

**You can echo this in your HTML file by**

```
<p><?php echo wt_get_category_count();?></p>
```